# Sample from aggregate data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have a Pandas dataframe with counts of objects in each category:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'color': ['red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'blue'], 'shape': ['round', 'square', 'round', 'square', 'round', 'square'], 'number': [10000, 1, 50, 500, 7, 3000]})

    color   shape   number
0   red     round   10000
1   red     square  1
2   green   round   50
3   green   square  500
4   blue    round   7
5   blue    square  3000
```

Each object has the following probabilities of being labelled 'A', 'B', 'C' or 'D':

```
score_dist = {'A': 0.1, 'B': 0.5, 'C': 0.25, 'D': 0.15}
```

What would be a good way of using these probabilities to get a dataframe of labelled aggregates? E.g. here is the bruteforce solution, where we unroll the aggregates into separate entries for each object, assign each object a label according to probabilities, and aggregate the result:

```
unrolled_df = []
for i,r in df.iterrows():
    colors = [r['color']]*r['number']
    shapes = [r['shape']]*r['number']
    unrolled_df.append(pd.DataFrame(data={'color': colors, 'shape': shapes, 'number': [1]*len(colors)}))
unrolled_df = pd.concat(unrolled_df, ignore_index=True)
rolls = np.random.rand(len(unrolled_df))
vals = np.array(['Unknown']*len(unrolled_df))
cumul_scores = {}
prob_left = 1
for s in score_dist.keys():
    cumul_scores[s] = prob_left
    prob_left = prob_left - score_dist[s]
for s in cumul_scores.keys():
    vals[rolls <= cumul_scores[s]] = s
unrolled_df['scores'] = vals
res = unrolled_df.groupby(['color', 'shape', 'scores']).sum().reset_index().sort_values(['color', 'shape', 'scores'])
```

The expected result is a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    color   shape   scores  number
0   blue    round   A       1
1   blue    round   B       1
2   blue    round   C       2
3   blue    round   D       3
4   blue    square  A       299
5   blue    square  B       1526
6   blue    square  C       723
7   blue    square  D       452
8   green   round   A       4
9   green   round   B       23
10  green   round   C       16
11  green   round   D       7
12  green   square  A       43
13  green   square  B       255
14  green   square  C       138
15  green   square  D       64
16  red     round   A       1000
17  red     round   B       5030
18  red     round   C       2479
19  red     round   D       1491
20  red     square  A       1
```

What would be a better/faster way to get the same result, i.e. without unrolling? The number of colors/shapes can be very large, i.e. df can have a million rows, and the number of each object could be up to a million.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an improvement on the brute-force solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'color': ['red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'blue'], 'shape': ['round', 'square', 'round', 'square', 'round', 'square'], 'number': [10000, 1, 50, 500, 7, 3000]})
score_dist = {'A': 0.1, 'B': 0.5, 'C': 0.25, 'D': 0.15}
df['cumulnum'] = np.cumsum(df['number'])
rolls = np.random.rand(df['cumulnum'].values[-1])
prob_left = 1
for s in score_dist.keys():
    cumul_scores[s] = prob_left
    prob_left = prob_left - score_dist[s]
prev_cumul_score = -1
for s in list(cumul_scores.keys())[::-1]:
    rolls_s = np.cumsum((rolls <= cumul_scores[s]) & (rolls > prev_cumul_score))
    prev_cumul_score = cumul_scores[s]
    df[s] = rolls_s[df['cumulnum'].values-1]
    df[s] = (df[s] - df[s].shift(1).fillna(0)).astype(int)
df = df.melt(id_vars=['color', 'shape'], value_vars=list(cumul_scores.keys()), var_name='scores', value_name='number').sort_values(['color', 'shape', 'scores'])
df = df[df['number'] != 0]
```